# My ceiling fan preference is to have 5 blades because it's quieter. Do helicopters ever have 5 rotor blades. Why?

Tags: helicopter

My home ceiling fans have 5 blades to reduce the wopwop sound in a quiet room.  It probably also moves air more efficiently at a lower spin rate.    Can a helicopter operate properly with 5 blades?

Comment: Related: [Why are three-bladed helicopters relatively rare?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32234) and [How to calculate the number of blades?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/73911)

Comment: Compare and contrast a fan on the ceiling, a helicopter rotor and a turbofan for a jet engine. They all move air from one place to another.

Comment: This is not an attempt at an answer, but I have seen a five-bladed fan on a diesel engine which had asymmetric blades in order to reduce noise.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, this is common.  It spreads the noise over a broader range of frequencies.  https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24327/why-are-the-blades-of-car-radiator-fans-unevenly-spaced

Answer (score 34):

[The most popular helicopter in the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-8) has 5 blades. It's rare in the US, but elsewhere it's like the 737 of rotorcraft. Altogether, 5-blade designs account for [about half of all helicopters](http://helicopterblog.com/?p=966) outside of North America.

Odd vs even blade count doesn't matter much for ceiling fans. The slower the fastest point of the blade is, the quieter the fan. More blades allow for a slower rotation speed for given diameter. Also, if the diameter is decreased, the peak noise frequency moves up, with some [extreme](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53771/could-a-dyson-fan-scale-up-to-be-used-as-a-bladeless-aircraft-engine) examples.

Odd blade counts are very common for Russian and European helicopters, as they make the noise quieter and less distinctive. The canceled [Comanche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing%E2%80%93Sikorsky_RAH-66_Comanche) "stealth helicopter" also used 5. Multi-blade rotors, especially with odd blade counts, are much more difficult to balance than simple 2-blade teetering rotors. However, once you get above 4 blades, it's a full balancing job anyway. Sikorsky easily switched from 6 to 7 blades in the [CH-53E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_CH-53E_Super_Stallion), and so did Mil from 5 in the Mi-6 to [8 in the Mi-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-26).

Even blade counts are more common in the US for historic reasons. While [Sikorsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_R-4) went with 3 blades from the start, [as did Mil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil_Mi-1), but [Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_47), who preferred a simple 2-blade rotor, captured the market first. The [Huey's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_UH-1_Iroquois) success reinforced this. So 2 or 4 blades are seen as more conservative, even though the Apache's 4-blade rotor is as complex as any 3- or 5-blade one (it has [dual teetering tail rotors](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43279/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-non-orthogonal-scissor-tail-rotor) though). American [heavy-lift helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikorsky_S-64_Skycrane) do use 5-7 blades.

For [low-cost GA helicopters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_R22), there's no choice but a 2-blade teetering rotor - articulated hubs are too complex for that market.

Comment: I can almost imagine, though I may be wrong, that if you add enough blades it actually becomes *easier* to balance - though "enough" might a silly amount for a helicopter. After all, balancing a disk (such as a car wheel) is pretty trivial.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner A car wheel doesn't rotate fast enough to affect its structural integrity. Rotors and turbine disks do, and balancing turbines is quite difficult. So I'd say the challenge increase slows down after 5 blades, but doesn't drop.

Comment: Is it odd blade counts that make things quieter, or just more blades? Would 6 blades be quieter than 4? Could you fairly easily balance 6 blades (3 teetering blades)?

Comment: @JaminGrey For a household fan, more blades. For a helicopter rotor, where blades are approaching Mach 1, odd number or uneven angle between the blades. As for balancing, the Apache has 2x2 teetering blades on its *tail* rotor, but its main rotor has 4 separate blades, requiring a full balance job, made only slightly easier by their orthogonality.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner: Your mind is taking you towards the [balanced centrifuge problem](https://mattbaker.blog/2018/06/25/the-balanced-centrifuge-problem/), but this is slightly different in that it assumes that a centrifuge has predetermined equidistant holes before you knew the amount of tubes you'd want to slot into it. Helicopter rotors are built with the explicitly knowledge of how many blades they will have, and so you can use any number of blades as long as they're equidistant (equiangular?) and it will be a balanced system. The only thing you can't do is build a one-bladed helicoper.

Comment: @GrimmTheOpiner It definitely gets easier to balance going from one blade to two.

Comment: Mi-8 ... who knew ?!

Answer (score 10):

Airbus H145 is a 5 bladed helicopter, recently certified by the FAA and EASA. https://www.airbus.com/en/newsroom/press-releases/2020-06-five-bladed-h145-receives-type-certification-by-easa

And there are 6,7, even 8 bladed helicopters.

Comment: Does that high a blade count not massively reduce the efficiency by putting each blade closer to the next blade's turbulence?

Comment: @Sneftel Yes and no. The rotor need enough wing area and airspeed for lift. Wide-chord blades create a lot of induced drag. Extremely long blades are heavy and flex excessively. For large helicopters, more rotors is the best solution, more blades the much cheaper second-best.

Comment: Most H145s and predecessors are 4-bladed though.

Comment: @M2FKXY the switch to 5 blade was for the H145 a necessity due to the need to increase the mtow further (and to improve noise and performance in general). There were no more room for improvement with the old 4 blades design. The 5 blades rotor derives from the [bluecopter platform](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Airbus-Helicopters/Airbus-Helicopters-H-135-Bluecopter/2752134).

Comment: Thanks a million. Went for an answer, stayed for an education!